# How to get producer of a PDF in google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail-addons, pdf.js

I am trying to write a gmail add-on where I iterate over all emails and create a report based on their producers. Iterating over emails is the easiest part and I have done that, however I can't find any way to get producer line of each PDFs.
So far I tried

- analyzing the blob, however this is something like writing a PDF library to parse all syntax. producer tag is not clearly present
- adding pdf.js, which is a third party open source tool to extract such information. However, I couldn't add it due to ES3 - ES6 support issue.

What's the best way to get the producer line of a PDF in google app script?

Thank you

Comment: If it is possible, can you provide sample PDF files you want to use?

Comment: Thank you for providing the sample. Can I ask you about the value you want from the sample PDF?

Comment: @Tanaike I gave a link to a document that doesn't contain any producer line :)
This is a good one: https://1drv.ms/b/s!AhueqKzeEHo9ZoKn7urs-BzMciU
I am expecting to retrieve "Adobe PDF library 15.00"

Comment: Thank you for updating it. From your updated PDF file, I could retrieve ``Adobe PDF library 15.00``. In order to remove your worries, can you provide several samples including the format of metadata with various patterns?

Comment: At the risk of crashing the UI, You can do all ES6 client side in the browser in the sidebar/modal dialogs from the add-on, where you can use pdf.js.

Comment: @Tanaike sorry for my late reply. If it works for all these PDFs, I would be more than happy and thankful: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AhueqKzeEHo90StHZ2qjNRJeAqEZ

Comment: @Dundar Thank you for replying and adding samples. From your shared PDF files, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? I'm not sure whether this script can be used for all PDF files. So if this didn't work and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the value of Producer from PDF file.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? In this sample script, from your shared PDF files, the value of Producer is retrieved by 2 regular expressions from the file content. Please think of this as one of several answers.

#### Sample script:

When you use this script, please set the folder ID of folder that PDF files are put. This script retrieves the value from all PDF files in a folder.

```
var folderId = "### folderId ###";
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFilesByType(MimeType.PDF);
var regex = [/Producer\((\w.+)\)/i, /<pdf:Producer>(\w.+)<\/pdf:Producer>/i];
var result = [];
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  var content = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var r = regex.reduce(function(s, e) {
    var m = content.match(e);
    if (Array.isArray(m)) s = m[1];
    return s;
  }, "");
  result.push({
    fileName: file.getName(),
    fileId: file.getId(),
    vaueOfProducer: r,
  });
}
Logger.log(result); // Result
```

#### Result:

This sample result was retrieved from a folder (my Google Drive) that the shared 3 PDF files were put.

```
[
  {
    "fileName": "2348706469653861032.pdf",
    "fileId": "###",
    "vaueOfProducer": "iText� 7.1.5 �2000-2019 iText Group NV \(iText; licensed version\)"
  },
  {
    "fileName": "Getting started with OneDrive.pdf",
    "fileId": "###",
    "vaueOfProducer": "Adobe PDF library 15.00"
  },
  {
    "fileName": "DITO-Salesflow-040419-1359-46.pdf",
    "fileId": "###",
    "vaueOfProducer": "iText 2.1.7 by 1T3XT"
  }
]
```

#### Note:

- About the file of `2348706469653861032.pdf`, the characters which cannot be displayed are included in the value of Producer.
- This is a sample script. So please modify this for your situation.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike. Thank you very much. 
I have adapted your code into mine, which just iterates over all emails with PDF attachment of a user. Then adds the attachment into Drive and opens it up from there. 
I receive an empty producer line for all PDFs. I am sure I do a mistake in my code. Can you help me?

https://textuploader.com/1da6i

or simply without Drive: https://textuploader.com/1da68

Comment: @Dundar Thank you for replying. About your new question, when I run your both scripts, I could confirm that the values of Producer from your 3 samples can be retrieved from both scripts. So I couldn't replicate your issue. I apologize for the inconvenience. By the way, can I ask you about the issue of my answer? If my answer was not useful for your situation, please tell me. Because I have to apologize and modify it.